# Converting items in a tuple Python

Tags: python

If I have the following tuple:

```
("200", "Harry", "50000", "Dog", "jumbo"),("200", "Harry", "50000", "Dog", "jumbo"),    ("200", "Harry", "50000", "Dog", "jumbo")
```

and I want to convert all the string numbers into ints so that I can format the ints correctly and do calculations so I can compare the list of tuples agaisnt each other e.g. print the tuples where the name is "harry" how would I go about doing it? My variable contains several tuples all with different information so I used a for loop to iterate and print them out individually but that is as far as I got.

Comment: The positions of the numbers are fixed? Or can they appear in any position in the tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
result = []
data = [("200", "Harry", "50000", "Dog", "jumbo"),("200", "Harry", "50000", "Dog", "jumbo"),    ("200", "Harry", "50000", "Dog", "jumbo")]
for item in data:
    result.append((int(item[0]), item[1], int(item[2]), item[3], item[4]))
```

Or even:

```
result = [((int(item[0]), item[1], int(item[2]), item[3], item[4])) for item in data]
```

This creates new tuples (as tuples are immutable) with integers instead of strings.

To find all tuples with `"Harry"` you can check whether `item[1] == "Harry"`.

Comment: I found the last option the best and got everything converted. Many thanks

Comment: This assumes the position of the numeric fields is fixed. If that's true, this might be the most explicit answer, but the OP never said it was true—and, if it is, it's probably better to use a `namedtuple` or a class instead of a `tuple` in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

### To convert all the string numbers into ints:

```
>>> a_tuple = ("200", "Harry", "50000", "Dog", "jumbo")
>>> tuple((int(x) if x.isdigit() else x) for x in a_tuple)
(200, 'Harry', 50000, 'Dog', 'jumbo')
```

### To find Harry:

```
>>> all_tuples = (
...     ("200", "Marry", "50000", "Dog", "jumbo"),
...     ("200", "Harry", "50000", "Dog", "jumbo"),
...     ("200", "Happy", "50000", "Dog", "jumbo"),
... )
```

If the position of the name is fixed (the second item):

```
>>> [t for t in all_tuples if t[1] == 'Harry']
[('200', 'Harry', '50000', 'Dog', 'jumbo')]
```

If the position is not fixed:

```
>>> [t for t in all_tuples if 'Harry' in t]
[('200', 'Harry', '50000', 'Dog', 'jumbo')]
```

Comment: This works only if the tuples cannot contain negative numbers, or numbers with sign.

Comment: @Bakuriu, Thank you for comment. How about `tuple((int(x) if x.lstrip('-+').isdigit() else x) for x in a_tuple)` ?

Comment: @falsetru: That works, but if you're not playing code golf, I think aiko's answer is a cleaner way to do it. (For one thing, in the Unicode world, there's no guarantee that `isdigit` and "works with `int`" are the same. For example, in Python 2.7, with Persian digits, `u'١'.isdigit() == False`, but `int('١') == 1`.)

Comment: @abarnert, Thank you for comment. I agree with you that alko's version is way to go. BTW, `u'١'.isdigit()` gives me `True` both in Python 2.7 / 3.3. See http://asciinema.org/a/6546

Comment: @falsetru: Weird. Apple 2.7.2 and 2.6.8 give me `True` on the very same machine that Homebrew 2.7.3 gives me `False`. Locale issue? No idea. Anyway, 2.x doesn't seem to document the behavior of `unicode.isdigit` beyond "…are digits…", so I guess this isn't a bug. (3.x defines it in terms of Unicode properties instead.)

Comment: @falsetru: So, scrap my example; here's a better one: superscript 1. `u'¹'.isdigit()` is guaranteed true in 3.3, and at least happens to be true in all 2.7 versions I've got lying around, but `int(u'¹')` raises a `ValueError` in all versions.

Answer (score 3):

I would use something like

```
def safe_int(v):
    try:
        return int(v)
    except ValueError:
        return v
```

This way:

```
>>> tup = ("200", "Harry", "50000", "Dog", "jumbo")
>>> tuple(map(safe_int, tup))
(200, 'Harry', 50000, 'Dog', 'jumbo')
```